# Site security - how to filter incoming traffic to a specific port

Tags: mysql, security, database, filter

Just ran a security test on ScanMyServer.com, the results showed a medium risk vulnerability:

Database Reachable from the Internet

Summary:
The remote host is running a database server that is reachable from the Internet.

A MySQL server is listening on this port.

Recommended Solution:
Filter incoming traffic to this port.

My question is how can I resolve it? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been downvoted, I just ran into the same kind of reports.

Answer (score 1):

If your BBDD only need connections for your apps in the same server, you can limit connections from a specific address (e.g. localhost) with the bind-address option. Configure this in your my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = localhost
```

Alternatively, you can force MySQL to use named pipes (a local-only method for connecting):

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = localhost
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
```

Of course, restart the MySQL Service after editing my.ini.